# Arrival Non-zero sum game?

Tags: arrival

In Arrival, how is a non-zero sum game more "science-y" than a win-win game? A non-zero sum game can be all of win-win, win-lose, and lose-lose. How is this an appropriate term to use to describe a situation where everyone wins? This is the same thing as describing as describing war as a conflict. Yes, a conflict describes war. But is it really accurate? In the same sense, yes, a non-zero sum game is describing the situation at hand, but it isn't more accurate than a win-win game. Can someone please clarify why the filmmakers put this scene in? It ruins the credibility of the film.

Answer (score 10):

A zero-sum game is by its nature adversarial. Anything that you gain, I lose, and vice versa. In a non-zero sum game, benefit is not mutually exclusive, so we can both gain from playing. You are correct that this is the same as a win-win, but this is described in scientific game theory parlance in the movie.

A non-zero sum game typically does not describe a lose-lose scenario, since both parties have the opportunity to maximize the utility of the outcome. There's no reason why both parties would take action to lose. A win-lose scenario is also better described as a zero-sum game - there's no reason for anyone to lose when it's a non-zero sum game. In practice, non-zero sum games are ones in which both players achieve maximum utility, i.e., a win-win.

Comment: +1 To expand (and maybe clarify a little) what Nuclear Wang is saying; in a zero sum game, any advantage one player gains is at the direct cost of the other player. In a non zero sum game, my 'win' is of no disadvantage to my 'opponent': hence, we are opponents no longer if there is no requirement to 'beat' each other.